# WebRTC : Can't talk at the same time

Tags: webrtc

I'm working on webRTC and I have a problem : with some user I can't talk at the same time (their microphone get automatically muted while I am talking)

Does somebody have some information about that ?

(I'm using simplePeer)

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to a misbehaving AEC (echo cancellation).
Try to disable AEC (and also AGC) on both side and it should fix the problem.

For WebRTC you can do it like this:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
audio: {
    echoCancellation: { exact: false },
    googEchoCancellation: { exact: false },
    googAutoGainControl: { exact: false },
    googNoiseSuppression: { exact: false },
      }
}
```